# nginx does not resolve upstream

Tags: nginx

I have two AP server, and I want to setup NGINX as a proxy server and load balancer.

here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
   #user  nobody;
    worker_processes  1;

    #error_log  logs/error.log;
    #error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
    #error_log  logs/error.log  info;

    pid        logs/nginx.pid;


    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;
        large_client_header_buffers 8 1024k;
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        sendfile        on;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        #keepalive_timeout  0;
        keepalive_timeout  650;

        send_timeout            2000;
        proxy_connect_timeout   2000;
        proxy_send_timeout      2000;
        proxy_read_timeout      2000;
        gzip  on;
        #
        # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
        # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf

        map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
          default Upgrade;
          ''      close;
        }

        upstream backend {
            server apserver1:8443;
            server apserver2:8443;
        }

        server {
          listen 8445 default ssl;
          server_name localhost;
          client_max_body_size 500M;
          client_body_buffer_size 128k;
          underscores_in_headers on;

          ssl on;
          ssl_certificate ./crt/server.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key ./crt/server.key;

          location / {
              proxy_pass https://backend;
              break;
          }
        }
    }
```

`apserver1` and `apserver2` are my AP server and in fact they are IP address.

when I visit the nginx via `https://my.nginx.server:8445`, I can get the AP container's default page. In my case, it is the JETTY server default page. that means the NGINX works.

if anything going correctly, user accessing to `https://my.nginx.server:8445/myapp` will get the log in page. if user has logged in, my app will redirect the user to `https://my.nginx.server:8445/myapp/defaultResource`.

when I visit via `https://my.nginx.server:8445/myapp` as a NOT-logged-in user, I can get the log in page correctly.

when I visit via `https://my.nginx.server:8445/myapp/defaultResource` directly as a logged-in user, I can get the correct page.

but when I visit the url `https://my.nginx.server:8445/myapp` as a logged-in user, (if correctly, the URL should be redirect to `https://my.nginx.server:8445/myapp/defaultResource`), but the nginx translate the URL to `https://backend/myapp/defaultResource`, and Chrome give me the following error:

```
The server at backend can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed....(omited)
```

nginx, seems not resolve the upstream `backend`. what's wrong with my configuration?

AND if I use http instead of https, everything goes well.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try with `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: @rednaw thx for reply. I did not try, because I have to use `https`. and I updated what I have tried, please check again.

Comment: You can always try to see if the problem is related to that...

Comment: what happens when you ping appserver1 and appserver2 from your nginx server?

Comment: @chuex currently, all the servers are available from others.

Comment: It almost seems to me that the block beginning with `location /myapp` is redundant. Any request to `/myapp` should already work using the prior root block. Can you try removing the `/myapp` block and see if it works?

Comment: @chuex thanks for reply, but I removed and run `nginx -s reload`, till can not access `/myapp`.

Comment: @rednaw I disabled the ssl, it works. but I need ssl. trying to find out...do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: If it works with http instead of https, then are you sure the ports are correct? Apparently http runs on port 8443, maybe you should use another port for https? Do you have access to the config of the app servers?

Comment: @rednaw I am sure that all the ports are correctly. and I found that if the user have not loged in, `https://my.nginx.server:8445/myapp` can be access(it is log in page). if the user logged in, accessing `https://my.nginx.server:8445/myapp` will be redirected to `https://backend/myapp/defaultResource` which is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the "resolver" directive to your configuration:

http://nginx.org/r/resolver

Comment: I'm sorry, could you tell me how to use a `resolver`? I don't really understand that directive